# Powershell 2.0 Default Printer Ouput-file Issues

Tags: powershell, printing, powershell-2.0, default

I am trying something that was simple in Powershell 3.0 that I am having a lot of difficulty achieving in Powershell 2.0. I am simply grabbing the default printer of a profile and outputting to a text file in the following format:

**default="Microsoft Print to PDF"**

In Powershell 3.0 that was done with the following line:

```
$DefaultPrinter = 'default="' + (Get-WmiObject win32_printer | Where-Object Default -eq $True).Name + '"'
$DefaultPrinter | out-file $File -encoding utf8
```

Powershell 2.0, I learned, did not like that at all. So after some trial an error I was able to get something almost like that with:

```
$DefaultPrinter = Get-WmiObject win32_printer | Where-Object {$_.Default -eq $True} | ft Name
$DefaultPrinter | out-file $File -encoding utf8
```

However, the output is now:

**Name**
**----**
**Microsoft Print to PDF**

For the life of me I cannot figure out the right format to get the exact same output as I do in 3.0 (No NAME title and including the "default=" and quotes surrounding the entry). I've tried everything I can think of and found online to no avail. Anyone have any ideas?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this:

```
$DefaultPrinter = "default=""$((Get-WmiObject win32_printer | Where-Object {$_.Default -eq $True}).Name)"""
```

Comment: That did the trick. Thanks! I don't think I would have figured this one out in the timeframe I am working in.